# Difference between AGC and AGAIN

Tags: datasheet, light-sensor

I'm going through an AMS optical sensor data sheet (AS7341) and keep seeing an "AGAIN" setting and can't figure out what it is. At first I thought that it was an Automatic Gain Control, but it doesn't so. There is no definition in the data sheet and my friend Google is not helping me much today.

Does anybody know what it could be? 
Is it something common and obvious?

https://ams.com/as7341

Thanks

Comment: Why would you not provide us with the datasheet when asking us what something in it means?

Comment: A quick google search of AMS optical sensor brings about a plethora of websites. Now you can't possibly expect us to search through all of them to find your exact issue. Please be reasonable and think of the reader when asking questions.

Comment: @BaldDude You think it's harsh, but think about our position. It is reasonable to go to a garage and ask a mechanic what is wrong with your car without bringing your car?

Comment: And clearly you need to grow thicker skin if you think that is lashing out. It's perfectly reasonable to be annoyed when you are trying to help someone who is showing no consideration to those trying to do the helping.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I do.

Comment: It looks like you like lashing out at people on other forums as well. Please note respect works both ways. If you think you smarter than everyone on this platform and we therefore have to treat you in a special way, then please don't bother asking a question. Becasue no one likes to help a person who is ungrateful.

Comment: Ouch. Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: @BaldDude EE.SE is not only a forum to answer questions but also a database of already answered questions. Its worth strongly depends on the quality of the questions. A lot of people with higher reputation are therefore in duty of reviewing questions from new users or posts if they are flagged by other users for some reason. This is tedious and demanding, hence reviewers often mutter to themselves why they seemingly have to explain every individual how to ask good questions. This leads to some frustration and sometimes to bad mood :)

Comment: I had never seen it like this. Thank you for pointing that out. With that in mind, taking a step back and reading the previous comments, I must agree that their comments were justified.

Comment: Since the datasheet is behind a "give us your contact info" wall, I'll simply comment that `AGC` may be automatic gain control, while `AGAIN` may be an analog gain value.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like AGAIN is the gain ratio:

[image]

Comment: But it literally says gain ratio on the side. I don't understand why this even warrents an answer...